# Go newbie: how to run goroutines shell?

Tags: go

I tried running [`shell-basic`](http://goroutines.com/shell) but nothing happens.  Here is what I tried:

> To run this example, download and install it with go get:

```
go get goroutines.com/shell-basic
```

which finishes silently and I see it downloaded the shell basic script but when i execute `shell-basic` i get:

```
$ shell-basic
-bash: shell-basic: command not found
```

did I do something wrong, or am i missing something?

what i'm interested in is running `go` as `scripts`..

Comment: Do you have your gopath setup? https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH

Comment: shell-basic is just an example of how you could script automated tasks using go. As a package (ie `go get goroutines.com/shell-basic`), it is really pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go get` will fetch the source and put it in your **Go path**, try `echo $GOPATH` in the shell. This is what happens if `go get` finishes silently.

Then you want to go to that source:

> `cd $GOPATH/src/goroutines.com/shell-basic`

**aftwards**, you must **run** `go install` inside the repo. (or you can run `go install /path/to/the/code`.

The source will then be put in `$GOPATH/bin`, and be executable.

Of course none of this will work if you don't have you `GOPATH` set up.

Comment: many thanks, this indeed worked.  I see that `$GOPATH/bin/shell-basic` is a binary.  So i don't understand what is `http://goroutines.com/shell` it says: `Write Shell Scripts in Go` but we have just created a `binary` as i understand a `script` is something which is not compiled, its just a script, so why does it claim it's possible to write shell scripts in `go`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you not set `GOBIN`.

You can follow：

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Or, try run `$GOPATH/bin/shell-basic`.Use your gopath replace `$GOPATH`.